# How to replace a string in excel between 2 slashes

Tags: excel

How could I replace a word in a url in excel which is between 2 slashes?

ex:

> www.google.com/temp/announce/news/p5638/zero.html
>   www.google.com/temp/announce/news/p4231/one.html

to

> www.google.com/temp/announce/news/**new**/zero.html
>   www.google.com/temp/announce/news/**new**/one.html

Comment: With a formula or in vba? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are always at the same depth, I think the easiest way to achieve that would be to split the column where you have the URLs using '/' as a separator and then replace the second to last column with 'new'. You would then merge the columns back into one.

Comment: Sorry to ask you...How to split that

Comment: @user1430114 You can use the "Text to Columns" option under the Data tab and select '/' as the delimiter. However, with urls of various 'depths' (# of slashes vary), the column you want to isolate may vary, as well.

Comment: Thanks...I have achieved what I want using your idea...splitting the columns 2 times (spliting front first and back second) with "fixed width". Thankss once again.

Comment: One is glad to be of service :)

Answer (score 1):

If the value `news/` is consistently just before the element you want to replace, you can use search & replace.  Press `ctrl+H` and type these values into the find and replace fields:

```
Search: /news/*/
Replace: /news/new/
```

Now, click `Replace All`.  Or, you can use a formula.  Assuming that the two values are in A1 and A2, then these formulas in B1 and B2 will do the trick for you:

```
=MID(A1,1,SEARCH("news/",A1,1)+LEN("news/")-1)&"new"&MID(A1,FIND("/", A1,SEARCH("news/",A1,1)+LEN("news/")),255)
=MID(A2,1,SEARCH("news/",A2,1)+LEN("news/")-1)&"new"&MID(A2,FIND("/", A2,SEARCH("news/",A2,1)+LEN("news/")),255)
```

Comment: thanks dear...its working good if the new is consistent..unfortunately it is not consistent...

Comment: You didn't say anything about a variable replacement value.  How does the new value change?  Is it perhaps in another column to the right of the URL?  What column is the URL in, and what column is the replacement value in?

Comment: Another thought...  Is this a one time thing or will you have to fix the URLs more than just once?

Comment: Thanks again...I am having around 13000 rows to alter...Also the url syntax is the same but the content may change for every URL.I am thinking of writing a small java code to do this :(

Comment: I have done using the option "Text to Columns". Thanks for your prompt response.